# Most appropriate language/library for low latency network application?

Tags: multithreading, networking, tcp

I'm planning a project that requires fast (as quick as possible) TCP server access. I've been testing out Java with Netty and C++ with BOOST. The project requires multithreading (if that affects any suggestions).

In my tests (not thorough, but enough to provide an insight) it would appear as though Java servers aren't anywhere near as quick to respond as those written in C or C++. Is this true or is my implementation/setup most likely wrong?

I've also got some experience in Objective C and if it were plausible, and the resulting application was fast enough, writing a server in Objective C would be great as it's the language I've got most experience with.

I know that someone will most likely respond saying that C is probably the best option for speed, but is there any significant overhead using an OOP language for networking? It seems as though the network speed would be the main bottleneck.

Thanks to anyone who is willing to impart some advice to an intrigued programmer :)

Comment: Java is not an option. Java is slow due to interpreter nature. C/C++ would be the best option but 90% of TCP performance depends on Operating System stack. In this case Linux beats OS X and Windows by a huge difference.

Comment: @AbiusX - I'd find it hard to believe it is that much slower than C++ for TCP communications. This is pretty much Java's forte, and I would imagine would be highly optimized code. Anyway, it is my understanding that Java isn't so much interpreted as compiled at load time.

Comment: Perhaps I'm having unreasonable expectations of speed. What sort of delay should there be between a client initiating a connection to a local (same machine) server and receiving an echoed message?

Comment: Due to the nature of network protocols, delay are miliseconds, not less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first important thing for you is to focus on **how** you design your server. Saying that it will be `multithreaded` doesn't tell us anything. Keep in mind that `multithreading` is far from being the *panacea*, in particular situations multithreading can be even harmful.

After that you have a clear understanding of how your server should work - see what languages (or even frameworks) are there that allow you to implement what you want with reasonable efficiency/complexity ratio.

Most people would indeed tell you that C++ (or C) is the language of choice for your task as there are no limitations and you have direct access to all the functionality OS gives you, but still - there are plenty of other mature languages/frameworks and picking the right tool depends on details of what exactly you want to do

Comment: Quite. For example, a typical implementation for a server in this kind of system is to create a pool of threads to service requests, so that you don't have to go through the expensive process of creating and destroying threads all the time. If you didn't do that, but Boost does it for you under the scenes while Netty doesn't, I could see you getting exactly what Marcus is seeing.